# Proof for the Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta, cauchy-sequences

Q

Prove the following :

$[{}^\exists r\in(0,1)　s.t.　{}^\forall n\in \mathbb{N},|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\leq r|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|]\Rightarrow $The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence


I understand that $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\leq r^n|a_{2}-a_{1}|$,but I don't found the arbitrariness of the Cauchy sequence and how to choose a good epsilon.


Thanks,for help.

Comment: you don't choose $\varepsilon$.

Comment: You take a generic $\epsilon >0$ and then show there is some $N$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$,  $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt:

Recall that for a sequence to be Cauchy, we need to find an $N$ such that $|a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$ for all $n,m \geq N$.

Now, pick an arbitrary $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $n>m$ without loss of generality.

Examining $|a_n - a_m|$ we see that we can rewrite it as

$$|a_n - a_m| = |a_n -a_{n-1} + a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + \cdots + a_{m+1} - a_m|$$

$$\leq ||a_n - a_{n-1}| + |a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}| + \cdots + |a_{m+1} - a_{m}||$$

$$\leq r^{n-1}|a_{2} - a_1| + \cdots + r^m|a_{2}-a_1|| \leq (n-m)r^m|a_{2}-a_1|$$

where the last line follows from repeated application of the assumption stated in the problem.

Since $r \in (0,1)$, we can pick an $N$ such that $\forall n,m \geq N$, $(n-m)r^m|a_2 - a_1| < \varepsilon$

And so we are done!

Edit: Fixed an inequality thanks to @infinity_hunter

Comment: Taking $n=2, m=1$ in your final inequality gives $|a_2 - a_1| < r^2|a_2-a_1|$ which means that $r^2>1$ and so $r>1$ which is of course not possible

Comment: @Infinity_hunter You're correct, thanks. I believe It should be $|r^{n}|a_{2}-a_1| + r^{(n-1)}|a_{2} - a_1| + \cdot + r^m|a_{2}-a_1|| \leq (n-m)r^m|a_{2}-a_1|$, where we exclude your case n=2, m=1 (as the hypothesis doesn't apply to this case.) And this last expression still converges to zero, so the result still holds.

Comment: I think still there is a problem. It is not clear why you can choose $N$ such that for given $\varepsilon$ , $\forall n,m \geq N
,(n-m)r^m|a_2 - a_1| < \varepsilon$. If it is possible, for given $\varepsilon$, keeping $m$ fixed and by using Archimedian property we can find a $n$ such that $(n-m)r^m |a_2-a_1| > \varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For $n >  m >1$
$$ \mid a_n -a_m \mid= \mid a_n - a_{n-1} + a_{n-1} - \cdots + a_{m+1} -a_{m} \mid  \le  \mid a_n - a_{n-1} \mid + \cdots + |a_{m+1} - a_m| \le (r^{n-2} + \cdots + r^{m-1} +r^{m-2})(|a_{2}-a_{1}|)$$

Since $0 <r<1$, the sequence $\langle1+r + r^2 + \cdots + r^{n}\rangle$ is converges,hence it is Cauchy.

Can you finish it?

Comment: I think your calculation is true only if $n$ and $m$ are either both even or both odd, not when one is even and the other is odd. Isn't it?

Comment: @ Math-Learner Why do you think so?

Comment: Because when you apply triangle inequality you have paired all the $a_i$'s. Hence there must be an even number of $a_i$!

Comment: @Math-Learner Let me give you an example, $|a_5 -a_2| = |a_5 -a_4 +a_4 - a_3 +a_3 -a_2|  \le |a_5-a_4| + |a_4-a_3| + |a_3-a_2|$. I am just adding and subtracting $a_i$ for $i = m+1, \dots ,n-2,n-1$

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt